# if any of the input field is not empty or not equal 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have stock table. I pull data out from the stack table using sql statemnet, use while loop to display on the webpage.

Please see picture.
[stock page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42irH.png)

I have an empty input field next to each line of stock. User should go though the stock and update stock by entering number in the empty field. So the way I want it ti work is user go though stock, enter stock numbers, than there is button at the bottom of page, which user must click to update the stock.

How I can hide the update button of all the fields = 0. if user input any field, the update button should appear, if user change the value, back to 0 it should hide again.

If I give input field an class "stock-val", than use .change function, it works, the problem is if user edit 1 stock item, than another, than another, and go back and mark previous as 0, the button goes hidden. I'm doing it by selecting class and .change will hide it if I mark it 0.

I need a way to show update button if at least 1 field is greater than 0, and hide if all  fields are empty are set to 0.

Thanks.

**My Html:**

```
    <div class="table-responsive">          
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result_miscellaneous) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_miscellaneous,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['description_stk']?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['clipbundleinfo_stk']?>"</td>
              <td><input class="form-control clips-assign-val" type="text" value="0"</td>
             </tr>
            <?php
            } 
        }
       ?> 
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".clips-assign-val").change(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();

        if(val > 0 ){
        $('#clip-bundles-assign-button1').show();
      }else {
     $('#clip-bundles-assign-button2').show();

    }

   });
  });
  </script>
```

So How to hide update button, if all the input fields are empty, and only show if at least 1 filed is not empty and more than 0.

Comment: Your logic is good thanks. But if I type value in first field, the update button will show. which is correct. than if i type value in second input field, than update button still there. however, if i go back and remove the value from the first field, the update button hides. but it should be not hidden as there is still value present in second field and user may want to submit that. So update button should be shown if there is value present in any of those fields and hidden of all those fields are empty. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you do it this way: `<input class="form-control" type="text" value="bla" data-old-value="bla" />`, then use script to compare old and new value on input `input` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At every change you need to check whether there is a non zero input value. This value could be in any other input element than the one that the `change` event happened on, so you should check all of them. This you can do with `each`. Here is a simplified HTML to demonstrate it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".clips-assign-val").change(function(){
  var allZero = true;
  $(".clips-assign-val").each(function () {
   var val = +$(this).val(); // convert string to number
   allZero = allZero && val === 0;
   return allZero; // if false, the loop will be aborted
  });
  $('#clip-bundles-assign-button1').toggle(!allZero);
  $('#clip-bundles-assign-button2').toggle(allZero);
   }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="clips-assign-val" value=0><br>
<input class="clips-assign-val" value=0><br>
<button id="clip-bundles-assign-button1">Not All Zero</button><br>
<button id="clip-bundles-assign-button2">All Zero</button>
```

NB: if you only want numeric input you could consider input `type="number"` instead of `type="text"`.